# How to prevent calabash-android "App did not start" error?

Tags: android, ruby, linux, calabash

I work on linux pc,

Ensured that AndroidManifest.xml has permission for INTERNET.
Tried command both with and without proxy, observation is same.

my real device has 4.1.1 android software,

AVD has 4.2.2 android with API level 17, Would that be problem?

I observe that, sample demo app gets launched on device, while I run 'calabash-android run AndroidDemoProject.apk...
but command throws error saying "App did not start" (RunTimeError).

Error details:

```
Feature: Demo feature

  Scenario: I can start my app                             # features/my_first.feature:3
    I wait for "Hello World, AndroidDemoProject" to appear
3707 KB/s (553745 bytes in 0.145s)
3045 KB/s (36301 bytes in 0.011s)
  App did not start (RuntimeError)
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/calabash-android-0.4.9/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:512:in `start_test_server_in_background'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/retriable-1.3.3.1/lib/retriable/retriable.rb:31:in `perform'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/retriable-1.3.3.1/lib/retriable/retriable.rb:59:in `retriable'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/calabash-android-0.4.9/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:511:in `start_test_server_in_background'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/calabash-android-0.4.9/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:92:in `start_test_server_in_background'
  /home/vijayvk/Downloads/AndroidDemoProject/calabash/features/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb:15:in `Before'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/my_first.feature:3 # Scenario: I can start my app
I wait for "Hello World, AndroidDemoProject" to appear

1 scenario (1 failed)
0 steps
0m22.337s
===========================================================================

$calabash-android run ../AndroidDemoProject.apk --verbose, leads to below output

013-09-04 15:42:45 - /usr/bin/ruby1.8 -S cucumber --verbose MAIN_ACTIVITY=sh.calaba.demoproject.AndroidDemoProjectActivity APP_PATH="/home/vijayvk/Downloads/AndroidDemoProject/AndroidDemoProject.apk" TEST_APP_PATH="test_servers/d06f94e698e2dfae7d59f229087ea78f_0.4.9.apk"
Code:
  * features/support/env.rb
  * features/support/app_installation_hooks.rb
  * features/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb
  * features/support/hooks.rb
  * features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb

Features:
  * features/my_first.feature
Parsing feature files took 0m0.002s


Feature: Demo feature

  Scenario: I can start my app                             # features/my_first.feature:3
    I wait for "Hello World, AndroidDemoProject" to appear
2013-09-04 15:42:46 - First scenario in feature - reinstalling apps
2013-09-04 15:42:46 - "/home/vijayvk/Development/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130219/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 00000D6300009613 forward tcp:34777 tcp:7102
2013-09-04 15:42:46 -
2013-09-04 15:42:46 - Uninstalling: sh.calaba.demoproject.test
2013-09-04 15:42:47 - Success
2013-09-04 15:42:47 - Uninstalling: sh.calaba.demoproject
2013-09-04 15:42:49 - Success
2013-09-04 15:42:49 - Installing: test_servers/d06f94e698e2dfae7d59f229087ea78f_0.4.9.apk
3153 KB/s (553745 bytes in 0.171s)
2013-09-04 15:42:54 -     pkg: /data/local/tmp/d06f94e698e2dfae7d59f229087ea78f_0.4.9.apk
Success
2013-09-04 15:42:55 - Installing: /home/vijayvk/Downloads/AndroidDemoProject/AndroidDemoProject.apk
4513 KB/s (36306 bytes in 0.007s)
2013-09-04 15:42:56 -     pkg: /data/local/tmp/AndroidDemoProject.apk
Success
2013-09-04 15:42:59 - Waking up device using:
2013-09-04 15:42:59 - "/home/vijayvk/Development/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130219/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 00000D6300009613 shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n sh.calaba.demoproject.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.WakeUp
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=sh.calaba.demoproject.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.WakeUp }
2013-09-04 15:43:01 - Starting test server using:
2013-09-04 15:43:01 - "/home/vijayvk/Development/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130219/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 00000D6300009613 shell am instrument -e class sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.InstrumentationBackend -e target_package sh.calaba.demoproject -e test_server_port 7102 -e main_activity sh.calaba.demoproject.AndroidDemoProjectActivity -e debug false sh.calaba.demoproject.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner

  App did not start (RuntimeError)
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/calabash-android-0.4.9/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:512:in `start_test_server_in_background'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/retriable-1.3.3.1/lib/retriable/retriable.rb:31:in `perform'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/retriable-1.3.3.1/lib/retriable/retriable.rb:59:in `retriable'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/calabash-android-0.4.9/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:511:in `start_test_server_in_background'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/calabash-android-0.4.9/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:92:in `start_test_server_in_background'
  /home/vijayvk/Downloads/AndroidDemoProject/calabash/features/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb:15:in `Before'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/my_first.feature:3 # Scenario: I can start my app
I wait for "Hello World, AndroidDemoProject" to appear

1 scenario (1 failed)
0 steps
0m26.737s
==========================================================================

$ calabash-android console AndroidDemoProject/AndroidDemoProject.apk

No test server found for this combination of app and calabash version. Recreating test server.
Done signing the test server. Moved it to test_servers/d06f94e698e2dfae7d59f229087ea78f_0.4.9.apk

irb(main):004:0> ARGV << "-v"
[
    [0] "--readline",
    [1] "--prompt-mode",
    [2] "simple",
    [3] "-v"
]
irb(main):005:0> start_test_server_in_background
2013-09-04 16:29:06 - Starting test server using:
2013-09-04 16:29:06 - "/home/vijayvk/Development/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130219/sdk//platform-tools/adb" -s 00000D6300009613 shell am instrument -e test_server_port 7102 -e class sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.InstrumentationBackend -e debug false -e target_package sh.calaba.demoproject -e main_activity sh.calaba.demoproject.AndroidDemoProjectActivity sh.calaba.demoproject.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner
RuntimeError: App did not start
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/calabash-android-0.4.9/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:512:in `start_test_server_in_background'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/retriable-1.3.3.1/lib/retriable/retriable.rb:31:in `perform'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/retriable-1.3.3.1/lib/retriable/retriable.rb:59:in `retriable'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/calabash-android-0.4.9/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:511:in `start_test_server_in_background'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/calabash-android-0.4.9/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:92:in `start_test_server_in_background'
    from (irb):5
```

Please let me know if there is any work around for this problem...

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Here at SO, we want to help you solve your problems. We don't do you debugging for you. As you mentioned, the different version could cause the problem. However, please review the ["How to Ask a Good Question" Guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and update your question appropriately!

Comment: Thank you screenmutt, I will try to edit my question as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I could resolve this when I had come across this error, by doing this:

1) Close the AVD and restart

2) If (1) doesnt fix the issue, uninstall the app, and execute reinstall_apps for your app again

3) if (2) doesnt fix the issue, delete the test servers folder and execute start_test_server_in_background again.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I tried your suggestions, but issue still persists.  reinstall_apps returns 'nil', and running start_test_server_in_background returns RuntimeError: App did not start.                                                                 The above mentioned observation is both for emulator and real device. I am stuck badly, but I know I might be missing some step.

Comment: Hope you have resigned your APK

Comment: Yes stamhaney I had done it using calabash-android resign, I figured out the problem. It was proxy issue, once I disable proxy it started working fine. Anyway thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I couldn't understand what is the proxy issue and how to disable it ...plz explain

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following solves the problem as well.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Reference:
http://www.luisdelarosa.com/2013/04/18/how-to-fix-problem-when-app-wont-start-when-testing-with-calabash-android/

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this way. 
Inside your ruby folder find file operations.rb. Path is like this "C:\Ruby23-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\calabash-android-0.7.3\lib\calabash-android". Open the file and find the block of code:

```
    Retriable.retriable :tries => 100, :interval => 0.1 do
              raise "App did not start" unless app_running?
```

Change "tries" parameter value on 300 instead of 100. It will help your app run in case of insufficiently productive device.
We've tested 6 different devices with default settings, but only 2 flagship smartphones (Samsung galaxy S6) could run app with "tries" parameter value => 100.
Now all our devices can run apps great!